# How do I fix a paradox/casual loop in a program splitting a FASTA file into multiple files?

Tags: python, string, function, file, loops

I created a file that takes a GFF3 file and a FASTA genome file and writes each exon from the GFF3 file into a new file and each gene group of exons into a new CDS file. The problem is that the exons write to a separate file but the CDS files have only a header and no CDS sequence.

I suspect that the problem begins at line

```
   if NMID != previous:
```

when I try to see whether the parent gene of the exon is the same as the previous exon. If it's not, then the current CDS file is written and closed before opening a new CDS file.

Any suggestions on fixing the if else clause beginning at

```
   if NMID != previous:
```

I think it's because I set the value previous inside the scope of the program.

How do I fix this paradox/casual loop in a program splitting a file into multiple files?

Input files:

ftp://ftp.flybase.net/genomes/Drosophila_melanogaster/dmel_r5.49_FB2013_01/fasta/dmel-all-chromosome-r5.49.fasta.gz This is the FASTA file

ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-77/gtf/drosophila_melanogaster/Drosophila_melanogaster.BDGP5.77.gtf.gz This is the gff3 file. Even though it's technically gtf, this is the file I am using as the gff3 file since it contains the exons.

---

I have a gff3 file and a FASTA genome file

The gff3 file is like this:

```
20 protein2genome exon 12005 12107 . - . ID=Blah_exon:1;Name=Blah:1;Parent=Blah

20 protein2genome exon 12108 12200 . - . ID=Blah_exon:2;Name=Blah:1;Parent=Blah

20 protein2genome exon 12005 12107 . - . ID=Blah_exon:3;Name=Blah:1;Parent=Blah

20 protein2genome exon 12342 12542 . - . ID=Blah_exon:4;Name=Blah:1;Parent=Blah

20 protein2genome exon 13005 13107 . - . ID=ABC_exon:1;Name=ABC:1;Parent=ABC
```

For each exon, I need to write a new file named gene_name_exon_number.fa

The header inside the file is this:

> gene_name exon_number  chromosome_name exon_start   exon_end

followed by the nucleotide bases in its chromosome using the start and end numbers

So the first exon file would look like:

> Blah 1 20 12005 12107
>   ACGGGCCTCAAAGCCGCGACACGACGGCTGTCGGCCGGTAACAGTAACCCCGGAGTGAACTCCTAT

Each exon will be a new file.

Also, I need to create a CDS file for each gene containing all the exons named gene_name_cds.fa

The header inside the file is this:

> gene_name number_of_exons chromosome_name cds_start cds_end cds_total_length

So the first CDS file would look like:

> Blah 4 20 12005 12542
>   ACGGGCCTCAAAGCCGCGACACGACGGCTGTCGGCCGGTAACAGTAACCCCGGAGTGAACTCCTAT
>   ACGGGCCTCAAAGCCGCGACACGACGGCTGTCGGCCGGTAACAGTAACCCCGGAGTGAACTCCTAT

Note: the nucleotide bases are just all of the nucleotide bases from the exons pasted together.

In the end, there will be several exon files and one CDS file for EACH gene in a GFF3 file containing several hundred genes and thousands of exons.

For the exon, I need this:

> gene_name exon_number  chromosome_name exon_start   exon_end

For the CDS, I need this:

> gene_name    number_of_exons   chromosome_name    cds_start   cds_end cds_total_length

cds_total_length should be cds_end-cds_start

```
from collections import defaultdict
from Bio import SeqIO

Exon_file = "exon.gff3"
FASTA_file = "melanogaster.fasta"

handle = open(FASTA_file, "rU")
FASTA_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"))
handle.close()

Exon_dict = {}
with open(Exon_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        Exon_dict[line.split()[-1].rsplit(";")[0].replace(":","")[3:]] = line.split()

previous = ""
CDS_sequence = ""
CDS_number_of_exons = int(0)
CDS_start = int(0)
CDS_end = int(0)
CDS_file = open (str("testfolder/" + "DUMMY" +"_CDS" + ".fas"),"w+")

for key, value in Exon_dict.iteritems():
    for k,v in FASTA_dict.iteritems():
        chromosome = value[0]
        direction = value[6]
        NMID = value[-1].split()[0].rsplit(';')[0][3:].rsplit("_")[0]
        if chromosome == k:
            start = value[3]
            end = value[4]
            exon_file = open (str("testfolder/" + key + ".fas"),"w+")
            exon_file.write(">" + key + " " + k + " " + start + " " + end + "\n")
            if direction == "+":
                exon_file.write(str(v.seq[int(int(start)-1):(int(end))]))
                CDS_sequence.__add__(str(v.seq[int(int(start)-1):(int(end))]))
            elif direction == "-":
                exon_file.write(str(v.seq[int(int(start)-1):(int(end))].reverse_complement()))
                CDS_sequence.__add__(str(v.seq[int(int(start)-1):(int(end))].reverse_complement()))

        if NMID != previous:
            CDS_file.write(">" + str(NMID) + " " + str(CDS_number_of_exons) + " " + str(chromosome) + " " + str(CDS_start) + " " + str(CDS_end) + " " + str(int(CDS_end)-int(CDS_start)) + "\n")
            CDS_file.write(CDS_sequence)
            CDS_file.close()
            CDS_file = open (str("testfolder/" + NMID +"_CDS" + ".fas"),"w+")
            previous = NMID
        else:
            CDS_number_of_exons += 1
            CDS_end += int(end)
            if start > CDS_start:
                pass
            else:
                CDS_start = start
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all of your code, but I'd guess your issue might have to do with using mode `"w+"` when opening the files. That mode will truncate the file, so if you ever open the same file several different times, you'll only see the data from the last time in the final output. Perhaps try `"r+"` (plus a `seek()` to the end of the file) or `"a"` mode instead.

Comment: @MrDoe777 This problem interested me so I rewrote your code.  However, there are a few confusing points.  1.) What value in each row of the exon file should be stored as the key in `Exon_dict`?  The value corresponding to `exon_id`, e.g. FBtr0330363:1?  2.) How many files of each type do you expect? I count 162331 exons in exons.gff3.

Comment: @wflynny Thanks! 1) It should be exon_id like FBgn0264003 2) If there are 162331 exons, there should 162331 exon files (1 for each exon) and less than 162331 CDS files (since there is only one CDS for each parent gene of a group of exons. Most parent genes should have four exons so a reasonable estimate would be 40582 CDS files). For example in the line, gene_id "FBgn0264003"; gene_version "5"; gene_name "mir-5613"; gene_source "FlyBase"; gene_biotype "pre_miRNA"; the key should be FBgn0264003

Comment: @MrDoe777, for StackOverflow, this question is of low quality due to the poor example code, extreme lack of question clarity, and little reusability for others.  But you've posted about this problem twice here, and on biostars too, so it's likely very important to your (research) work.  I spent an hour yesterday/today trying to make sense of this problem, but there are still some problematic/unclear things.  Because it's not perfect, here's a [pastebin snippet](http://pastebin.com/qRmvKRkS) instead of an answer.  Please ensure future questions on StackOverflow are simpler/clearer.

Comment: @wflynny Thanks! I will try to be more clear on future questions. Do you have any suggestions for how to be more clear?

Comment: @MrDoe777  For a start, follow the guidelines to ask a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Supply a concrete set of inputs and what the desired output is.  Your example output isn't consistent with your question or code, and it isn't clear how to create it.  In addition though, you're question is very domain specific using jargon that the vast majority of users here won't be able to understand.